# PHP - If value is null, set to default & insert

Tags: php, mysql

i have an insert form, and 2 of the values are type numbers, and 1 is type date. As they are unrequired, if left blank and the qry is executed, the error returned is "Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Pieces' at row 1" & this will occur for weight & arrival, if the one before has a value.

So to fix the issue, by finding is the value is null, and setting it to DEFAULT (as this would insert the value as null onto the db as default=null), i tried the code below, but the error (Incorrect integer value: 'DEFAULT' for column 'Pieces' at row 1) comes out, and i assume its the ' ' which is interfering, as that code would insert 'DEFAULT', when it should be DEFAULT. So how could i amend the code to remove the ' '.

Comment: PHP Version used here?

Comment: What is your table structure? Make sure that the columns you might want to leave blank aren't declared as `NOT NULL`

Comment: You want 'DEFAULT' to be used when the value is null, correct? Shouldn't the code be `if(is_null($var))` instead of `if(!is_null($var))` ? Also, you definitely need to put DEFUALT in quotes, otherwise php will not know that it is a string.

Comment: If the table has a default value, pass in NULL (unquoted), not DEFAULT.

Comment: You need to wrap `DEFAULT` in quotes. At the moment, PHP is looking for a constant named `DEFAULT`.

Comment: You code is highly insecure. You should consider using `prepared statements` or something like `mysqli_real_escape_string `.

Comment: PHP5 i believe, if statement was just top of my head, and didnt work, incase thats why you are asking

Comment: But you got it, REMOVE all `'` from your SQLQuery and change all check like `else { $wgt = "'$wgt'"; } ` that can fix it.

Comment: `('$awb',DEFAULT,` of all things should be `('$awb','DEFAULT',` - as previously stated ( Edit: by @BenM ) , that `DEFAULT` with no quotes around it is treated as a constant; did you declare it as a constant? along with your other `$X= DEFAULT;`?

Comment: you have answers below; the comments are piling up too high here. Edit: In the meantime http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: On the backend, phpmyadmin, default = null. Thats why i use default in the mysql query, as theres another value which isnt being assigned anything in the form. When i change the check to how @JustOnUnderMillions suggested, how do i call it in the mysql , just as $pcs without ''? result of that outputs "incorrect int value: '' for column pieces", so default isnt being read literally by mysql to insert is as a null value

Comment: Taken me awhile to go through everything, whats occuring is, even when using if(is_null($pcs)){ $pcs = "DEFAULT";} else {}, the sql query is reading it as ' DEFAULT ' , not DEFAULT. so it doesnt set it to null.

Comment: There is a whole lot of talk here about `DEFAULT` and your `if`s. Just ignore all that and change your query to use parameters. Then if a variable is empty, the query will just insert whatever the column default value is.

Comment: Thanks @CptMisery, going to give it a try later on, would this be along the lines as to what you've mentioned? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Yes. PDO is my preferred method. You can also use `mysqli_*` functions, but stay away from `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Havent used PDO before, if you could CptMisery, check my edited code, attempting to use it, but not 100% functional yet

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set a variable value to any string when it is empty, use `empty()` function to check whether given variable is empty. And if it is, assign the default value.

For example, instead of all these `if`s use a ternary operator (which is shorter and IMO more readable) and use this in lines where assignment happens.

```
$pcs = !empty($_POST['Pieces']) ? $_POST['Pieces'] : 'DEFAULT';
```

Comment: Output from using your suggested code: Incorrect integer value: 'DEFAULT' for column 'Pieces' at row 1.  Just req DEFAULT to be passed through but obviously cant have it with the '' in statement or else unable to handle request

Comment: @CS88 then just replace the `'DEFAULT'` literal with some other value which will be assigned when pieces are empty.

Answer (score -1):

You can also validate null and empty values by doing:

```
if(is_null($pcs) || $pcs == '') //do your thing;
```

Comment: still outputting incorrect int value: '' for column 'Pieces' at row 1